# Can no longer run individual instrumented tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, instrumented-test

For two months or so now I haven't been able to run individual UI tests in Android Studio. Right clicking on the test name and then `run <test name>` just give me the error `No tests were found`. If I right click on the class name and then click `run <testing class name>`, it successfully runs all the tests in the class. So in order to just run an individual test in a class I have to resort to commenting out all the tests I don't want to run and then clicking on run from the class name which is a pain. This used to work fine a couple of months ago.

I really don't have much more information to go off of. The only output is

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49178', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49178', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.mypackagename.android.TestClassName"
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a reportable bug. Do a Help->Submit Feedback; I'm sure they'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Have u annotated with @Test above all test cases?

Comment: yep @SushantSomani, the tests wouldn't run from the class level if they weren't annotated as tests

Comment: What is the solution?  I have the same problem.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it just started working again with a newer version of AS

Answer (score 0):

Even years later (August 2022), same issue with latest Android Studio IDE;

In my experience, Android Studio 3.x was still able to run individual tests (no matter if individual-test-method or individual-test-class).

I will try updating Gradle, and report back if that helps ;-)

> **Update;** No, the issue does not seem Gradle related.
>
> (I tried both downgrade and update of Gradle, but the issue remains, and only downgrading Android-Studio to v3.x fixes the issue for me.)

Comment: I am facing this today, using Dolphin RC 1